# React App - Unexpected token, expected ","

Tags: javascript, reactjs, zxing

I am creating a react APP. I am getting this below error while compiling

```
     Line 23:11:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","
    
      21 |         .decodeFromInputVideoDevice(null, document.getElementById(
      22 |           "video"
    > 23 |         ) as HTMLVideoElement)
         |           ^
      24 |         .then(resolve)
      25 |         .catch(reject);
      26 |     })
```

My Component code is

```js
import * as React from "react";
import * as zxing from "@zxing/library";

const Video = () => {
  const [code, setCode] = React.useState<string>("");
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = React.useState<string>("");
  const [recording, setRecording] = React.useState<boolean>(false);

  const reader = new zxing.BrowserMultiFormatReader(null, 1000);

  const start = (e: React.SyntheticEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setRecording(true);

    const p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        reader.stopAsyncDecode();
      }, 60000 * 1);

      reader
        .decodeFromInputVideoDevice(null, document.getElementById(
          "video"
        ) as HTMLVideoElement)
        .then(resolve)
        .catch(reject);
    })
      .then((result: zxing.Result) => {
        setCode(result.getText());
        stopStreamedVideo();
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err.message);
        if (
          err.message !==
          "Video stream has ended before any code could be detected."
        ) {
          setErrorMessage(
            "Ha ocurrido un error de lectura de código, intentelo nuevamente."
          );
        }
        stopStreamedVideo();
      });

    p1.catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  };

  const stop = (e: React.SyntheticEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    reader.stopAsyncDecode();
    stopStreamedVideo();
  };

  function stopStreamedVideo() {
    const videoElem: any = document.getElementById("video");
    setRecording(false);

    if (videoElem && videoElem.srcObject) {
      let stream = videoElem.srcObject;
      let tracks = stream.getTracks();

      tracks.forEach((track: MediaStreamTrack) => {
        track.stop();
      });

      videoElem.srcObject = null;
    }
  }
  return (
    <div className="container-fluid">
      <div className="w-100 row align-items-center">
        <div className="row">{errorMessage}</div>
        <div className="row">{code}</div>
        <div className="row">
          {!recording && (
            <button id="btnStart" onClick={e => start(e)}>
              Start video recording
            </button>
          )}

          {recording && (
            <button id="btnStop" onClick={e => stop(e)}>
              Stop recording
            </button>
          )}
        </div>
        <div className="row">
          <video id="video" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Video;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Could you please help me in this why I am getting this error.

**Edit:**

Problem Solved:

The problem is because of "as HTMLVideoElement". I have removed that and it started working.

Comment: Please show ALL the code

Comment: I have added the code

Comment: Look at ```e: React.SyntheticEvent``` try ```(e)``` instead

Comment: @Mulli still same error.

Comment: Maybe some strange character between ```render``` and ```.decodeFromInputVideoDevice(null, document.getElementById(```?

Comment: No checked nothing is there

Comment: Start removing parts of the code, until you get the minimum to regenrate the problem. I think that along the way you will find it.

Comment: @Mulli Found the issue. the problem is because of "as HTMLVideoElement". I have removed that and the application started working. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because of "as HTMLVideoElement". I have removed that and it started working.